# Why does my flash SWF video get stuck sometimes on my website?

Tags: html, video, flash

Below is the code I have embedded on the HTML5 webpage, but it sometimes gets stuck in all browsers in multiple computers.

```
     <embed src="ealco.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%" height="349"></embed>
```

Your answers will be much appreciated.....

Comment: It is not an HTML issue. Can you post a link to the swf so someone (probably me) can try and debug it?

Comment: @totbar sorry this is the link actually http://www.ealco.co.uk/ealco.swf